# How to not have a null item in a collection in .net mvc with html 5 input with attribute "multiple"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, html, input

This is my View Model.

```
Public Class SomeClass   
    Public Property Attachments As IEnumerable(Of System.Web.HttpPostedFileBase)
    'other stuff
    'other stuff
End Class
```

And in my view:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(Function(model) model.Attachments, New With {.type = "file", .multiple = True})
```

When I select at least one image to upload then everything works correctly. However, when I don't upload any image, the collection contains one item but that item is null.
[image]

Is there a way for me to make where when there is nothing to upload it just return an null collection or an empty collection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The single item contains null value inside `IEnumerable(Of HttpPostedFileBase)` when form submit with no files uploaded can be traced back by browser HTTP POST request headers, which indicates this behavior is by-design.

This is a sample POST request for a page contains file input with multiple upload enabled (some irrelevant parts removed for brevity):

> Host: "localhost:[port]"
>
> User-Agent: "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:54.0) Gecko/20100101
>   Firefox/54.0"
>
> Accept:
>   "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8"
>
> Accept-Language: "en-US,en;q=0.5"
>
> Accept-Encoding: "gzip, deflate"
>
> Content-Type: "multipart/form-data;
>   boundary=---------------------------17618158692582"
>
> Referer: "http://localhost:[port]/Example/Upload"
>
> Connection: "keep-alive"

And this is what I get in parameters section (notice empty filename parameter in bold):

> -----------------------------17618158692582
>
> Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Attachments"; **filename=""**
>
> Content-Type: application/octet-stream

The empty value from `filename` parameter becomes reason why `IEnumerable(Of HttpPostedFileBase)` contains single item which stores `Nothing` (null) value & `Count` result from the collection returns 1, same value as `Request.Files.Count` property.

Here are test conditions:

```vb
Dim fileCount As Integer = model.Attachments.Count() 'returns 1

Dim firstFile As HttpPostedFileBase = model.Attachments.First() 'returns Nothing

Dim requestCount As Integer = Request.Files.Count 'returns 1
```

Note that there's no other way to remove `filename` parameter on `Content-Disposition` header (so that it's impossible to empty `HttpPostedFileBase` collection on form submit), but you can check if the collection state has `Nothing` value using `model.Attachments.First`, or using for-each loop like this:

```vb
If model.Attachments.Any() Then
    For Each file As HttpPostedFileBase In model.Attachments
        If file IsNot Nothing Then
            ' do something
        Else
            ' other stuff
        End If
    Next
End If
```

Reference:

[ASP.NET MVC – Multiple Files Upload Bug or by-design issue?](http://michaelsync.net/2014/04/29/asp-net-mvc-multiple-files-upload-bug-or-by-design-issue)